# Arduino loses usb connection

Tags: arduino, h-bridge

When I connect the 5v power supply of my arduino to my h-bridge the usb connection is dropped and the on LED dims. What is causing this?

Comment: Provide all relevant details: exact circuit, motor ratings, power supply details (from USB? very bad idea for powering  motor..).

Comment: Either a shortcircuit or a overloaded usb cable, but without more information it is hard to tell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your motor tries to draw to much current from the USB through the H-bridge. The USB can only provide 100 mA and your motor must be rated for more than that.

The safest option is to connect your H-bridge/motor from a separate power supply. As *Wouter* says, you should provide more information about your Arduino, the H-bridge and the motor you're trying to control, otherwise there's no way of telling what would work and what wouldn't.