# USB connection dropped and "on" LED dims using Arduino + H-Bridge 

Tags: arduino, h-bridge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Arduino loses usb connection](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34318/arduino-loses-usb-connection)

When I connect the 5v power to an H-bridge I constructed the Arduino loses its USB connection to my computer and the "on" LED dims.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB can only supply 500mA. If the load connected to your H-Bridge draws more than this then you'll have problems.

Provide a separate power source for the load (via the H-Bridge) rather than using the Arduino's 5V line.